# Undefined index PHP - FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

When im trying to read some data from my data class i get a notice : undefined index.

Here is the script :

```
$data = $data_aanbieding->week_aanbieding($week, $jaar);

$productnaam = $html_entities->html_ent($data['p_productnaam']);
$verkoopprijs = $html_entities->html_ent($data['a_verkoopprijs']);
$aanbiedingsprijs = $html_entities->html_ent($data['a_aanbiedingsprijs']);
$hoeveelheid = $html_entities->html_ent($data['p_hoeveelheid']);
$eenheid = $html_entities->html_ent($data['p_eenheid']);
```

Those indexes i get the notice on, here the data class :

```
$result = $this->mysqli->query(
<<<EOT
                SELECT
                    aanbiedingen.id as a_id,
                    aanbiedingen.product_id as a_product_id,
                    aanbiedingen.week as a_week,
                    aanbiedingen.jaar as a_jaar,
                    aanbiedingen.verkoopprijs as a_verkoopprijs,
                    aanbiedingen.aanbiedingsprijs as a_aanbiedingsprijs,
                    producten.product_id as p_id,
                    producten.productnaam as p_productnaam,
                    producten.hoeveelheid as p_hoeveelheid,
                    producten.eenheid as p_eenheid

                FROM aanbiedingen
                INNER JOIN producten ON producten.product_id = aanbiedingen.product_id

                WHERE week={$week}
                AND jaar={$jaar}
                ORDER BY p_productnaam  

EOT
            );
            if($result){
                $waardes = array();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $waardes[]=$row;
                }
                return $waardes;
            }
```

Comment: Which line of the code is the error on? (Please copy and paste the line, instead of giving the line number) And can we see the value of `print_r($data)` please?

Comment: Could you give the exact error/notice ([PHP manual for mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php))

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, what if you try to change `$waardes[]=$row;` in `$waardes=$row;` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a notice, meaning that one of your array keys (indexes) has not been defined. You can turn of notice reporting using the [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function or setting it in your php.ini file. You could also make sure that all the array records you're using actually have a value.

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` might do the trick (at the top of your script).

**EDIT**
Judging from your own reply, you should be looking at `$data[0]['p...']` instead of just `$data['p...]`; the data you want seems to be stored inside a nested array, through which you should loop to access all the fetched `$data` records.